# Custom Pygments styles in minted not taking effect

Tags: minted, pygments

I have a fairly minimal document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{github}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I've installed the github Pygments style with `sudo pip2 install pygments-style-github`.

```
$ pygmentize -L styles | grep git
* github:
Port of the github color scheme.
```

And yet, when I compile the document, the colours used in the syntax highlighting are the same as if the `\usemintedstyle{github}` command was missing:

[image]

I can print out the CSS rules for the style using `pygmentize -S github -f html` without any problems, which makes me think the style is installed correctly. Other built-in styles such as "borland" work correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by deleting the `_minted-a/` directory and recompiling.

The root cause of the problem was an attempt to use a style with a numeric name prior to the MRE presented in the question. Due to macro restrictions, [styles with names including an integer cause the style to fall back to the default one](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/210#issuecomment-408090405).